# Aligned attribute in C

Tags: c

I have seen so many question asked in SO regarding the aligned attribute, but no where i found the advantage or when to use of this(I mean where exactly and in which scenarios we have to use this concept).Can any one give the clear picture of it. just copied one program from one the SO question one program for aligned attribute reference

```
int main( )
{
    struct data
    {
        int a    __attribute__( ( aligned ( 8 ) ) ) ;
        char ch  __attribute__( ( aligned ( 1 ) ) ) ;
        float s  __attribute__( ( aligned ( 4 ) ) ) ;    
    } ; 
    struct data e ;
    printf ( "\n%u %u %u", &e.a, &e.ch, &e.s ) ;
    printf ( "\n%d", sizeof ( e ) ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Well you must read the FAQ's before start posting questions on SO!!!

Answer (score 1):

First use case is when you have a `char` array which you use to store something else, then you need to force the allign to the proper type.

Second scenario are binary protocols, when you are reading a specifically laid out data (from network, or files), then you need to force the layout using aligned.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of alignment mostly portrays to performance and portability. If you don't understand the alignment requirements of the platform you are using your code might not necessarily be able to run there or it will break as soon as someone move the code (or data) that isn't properly aligned to that platform.

Depending on things such as hardware and OS some of this is handled for you but you're going to incur some penalty for braking the alignment rules. By default, old Windows versions used to crash processes in the event of an alignment fault, today Windows will be able to recover but at the costs of additional CPU cycles.

the aligned attribute is a GCC specific feature to force the alignment (it has nothing to do with the C-language), alignment is at what multiple of some number your data has to be laid out in memory. The compiler will then insert garbage in your data structure to ensure that the constraints you've imposed on the compiler are met.

Let's take the example in your question:

```
struct data
{
    int a    __attribute__( ( aligned ( 8 ) ) ) ;
    char ch  __attribute__( ( aligned ( 1 ) ) ) ;
    float s  __attribute__( ( aligned ( 4 ) ) ) ;
} ;
```

We'll assume that in this case both `int` and `float` native size on our imaginary platform is 4 bytes.

The final struct, as laid out in memory will be closer to

```
struct data
{
    int a;        // 0x00   
    int junk0     // 0x04
    char ch;      // 0x08
    char junk1[3] // 0x09
    float s;      // 0x0C
} ;
```

I'm not sure if the compiler will pad the first integer, so that it actually occupies 8 bytes in the final struct. It won't be 64-bit just because of the padding, I find it strange because it would assume that the struct be placed on even 64-bit addresses only, so in a 32-bit architecture, if you alloc memory, only if that memory is aligned at an address that is a multiple of 8 is this OK. Maybe that's to make it more portable, to make sure it behaves the same on 32-bit as 64-bit.

The compiler can chose to be much more aggressive and actually waste a lot more space but there's pack directives to combat that. If native binary compatibility is really important to you then these things really matter.

Comment: "I'm not sure if the compiler will pad the first integer"
No, that's a place where the standard explicitly forbids placing any padding. The address of the first member of a struct and the address of the struct must be the same.

Check Section 6.7.2.1 (15) in the n1570 draft of the C2011 standard.