# what is aligned attribute and what are the uses of it

Tags: c, linux

I have following lines in the code

```
  # define __align_(x)  __attribute__((aligned(x)))
```

I can use it `int i __align_;` what difference does it makes like like

I am using aligned attribute as above or if I am just creating my variable like `int i;` does it differ in how variable get created in memory?

Comment: in what code? compiled how? guessing you didn't write it, since you don't know what it does, so specify where you saw it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aligned attribute in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901917/aligned-attribute-in-c)

Comment: `I can use it int i __align_;` no you can't, it's a macro function. You can use it like `int i __align_(double);`

Comment: just consider if I have a `struct abc` which contain only single `char c`; and I have attribute like `#define __align_  __attribute__((aligned(12)))` and and I am on 32 bit system so 4 bit int arithmetic on the system the if I do `struct abc obj __align_` then will my obj will cover 12 bytes in memory with padding

Comment: @underscore_d please see my comment above

Comment: As a side note, `__attribute__((aligned(x)))` is a non-standard gcc extension that went obsolete 10 years ago. The C standard has `_Alignas`, use that instead.

Comment: You mean, if you have a totally different definition of `__align_` than the one in your quesion, then you can use it in the way you claimed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can use it `int i __align_;` what difference does it makes like like

This will not work because the macro is defined to have a parameter, `__align_(x)`. When it is used without a parameter, it will not be replaced, and the compiler will report a syntax error. Also, identifiers starting with `__` are reserved for the C implementation (for the use of the compiler, the standard library, and any other parts forming the C implementation), so a regular program should not use such a name.

When you use the macro correctly, it changes the normal alignment requirement for the type.

Generally, objects of various types have alignment requirements: They should be located in memory at addresses that are multiples of their requirement. The reasons for this are because computer hardware is usually designed to work with groups of bytes, so it may fetch data from memory in groups of, for example, four bytes: Bytes from 0 to 3, bytes from 4 to 7, bytes from 8 to 11, and so on.

If a four-byte object with four-byte alignment requirement is located at a multiple of four bytes, then it can be read from memory easily, by loading the group of bytes it is in. It can also be written to memory easily.

If the object were not at a multiple of four bytes, it cannot be loaded as one group of bytes. It can be loaded by loading the two groups of bytes it straddles, extracting the desired bytes, and combining the desired bytes in one processor register. However, that takes more work, so we want to avoid it. The compiler is written to automatically align things as desired for the C implementation, and it writes load and store instructions that expect the desired alignment.<sup>1</sup>

Different object types can have different alignment requirements even though they are bound by the same hardware behavior. For example, with a two-byte `short`, the alignment requirement may be two bytes. This is because, whether it starts at byte 0 or byte 2 within a group (say at address 100, 102, 104, or 106), we can load the `short` by loading a single group of four bytes and taking just the two bytes we want. However, if it started at byte 3 (say at address 103), we would have to load two groups of bytes (100 to 103 and 104 to 107) to get the bytes we needed for the `short` (103 and 104). So two-byte alignment suffices for this `short` even though the hardware is designed with four-byte groups.

As mentioned, the compiler handles alignment automatically. When you define a structure with multiple members of different types, the compiler inserts padding so that each member is aligned correctly, and it inserts padding at the end of the structure so that an array of them keeps the alignment from element to element in the array.

There are times when we want to override the compiler’s automatic behavior. When we are preparing to send data over a network connection, the communication protocol might require the different fields of a message to be packed together in consecutive bytes, with no padding. In this case, we can define a structure with an alignment requirement of 1 byte for it and all its members. When we are ready to send a message, we could copy data into this structure’s members and then write the structure to the network device.

When you tell the compiler an object is not aligned normally, the compiler will generate instructions for that. Instead of the normal load or store instructions, it will use special unaligned load or store instructions if the computer architecture has them. If it does not, the compiler will use instructions to shift and store individual bytes or to shift and merge bytes and store them as aligned words, depending on what instructions are available in the computer architecture. This is generally inefficient; it will slow down your program. So it should not be used in normal programming. Decreasing the alignment requirements should be used only when there is a need for controlling the layout of data in memory.

Sometimes increasing the alignment requirements is used for performance. For example, an array of four-byte `float` elements generally only needs four-byte alignment. However, some computers have special instructions to process four `float` elements (16 bytes) at a time, and the benefit from having that data aligned to a multiple of 16 bytes. (And some computers have instructions for even more data at one time.) In this case, we might increase the alignment requirement for our `float` array (but not its individual elements) so that it is aligned to be good with these instructions.

### Footnote

1 What happens if you force an object to be located at an undesired alignment without telling the compiler varies. In some computers, when a load instruction is executed with an unaligned address, the processor will “trap,” meaning it stops normal program execution and transfers control to the operating system, reporting an error in your program. In some computers, the processor will ignore the low bits of the address and load the wrong data. In some computers, the processor will load the two groups of bytes, extract the desired bytes, and merge them. On computers that trap, the operating system might do the manual fix-up of loading the bytes, or it might terminate your program or report the error to your program.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute tells the compiler that the variable in question must be placed in memory in addresses that are aligned to a certain number of bytes (`addr % alignement == 0`).
This is important because the CPU can only work on some integer values if they are aligned - such as `int32` must be 4 bytes aligned and `int64` must be 8 bytes aligned, pointers need to be 4/8 (32/64 bit cpu) aligned too.
The attribute is mostly used for structures, where certain fields within the structure must be memory aligned in order to allow the CPU to do integer operations on them (like `mov.l`) without hitting a BUS ERROR from the memory controller.

If structures aren't properly aligned, the compiler will have to add extra instructions to first load the unaligned value into a register with several memory operations which is more expensive in performance.

It can also be used to bump performance in more performance sensitive systems by creating buffers that are page aligned (4k usually) so that paging will have less of an impact, or if you want to create DMA-able buffer zones - but that's a bit more advanced...

Comment: so if I have a `struct abc` which contain only single `char c;` and I have attribute like `#define __align_  __attribute__((aligned(12)))` and and I am on 32 bit system so 4 bit int arithmetic on the system the if I do `struct abc obj __align_` then will my `obj` will cover 12 bytes in memory with padding

Comment: @Alex I don't think the `aligned` attribute will impact padding. But if you don't define the alignment attribute the compiler can reasonably place your `abc` struct in any memory address (even odd numbers) since it's just 1 char and it won't impact performance.
If you do use `aligned(12)` the addresses will be 12 bytes aligned, but the compiler can use the space to place other variables in it.

Comment: so 12 bytes long memory will contain `struct abc` but if I hadn't used it then it would be much less space for alignment means my struct abc obj would be done in 4 bytes if this same as int arithemtic on system?

Comment: `If you do use aligned(12) the addresses will be 12 bytes aligned, but the compiler can use the space to place other variables in it` so my obj may get corrupted

Comment: No, the attribute refers to the starting address of the struct, not it's size in memory.
It just means that if you have several objects in your scope and your aligned struct is one of them the compiler will arrange them in a way that your aligned object will start at an address that is aligned as requested. The size of the struct won't change as the result of this attribute. `sizeof` will still return the same value, aligned or not.

Comment: `I don't think the aligned attribute will impact padding.` It does impact padding, because if you do an array of things, the next array element has to start at proper address and the distance between array elements is the size. So `struct abc arr[2]` then `&arr[1]` has to start at `%12 == 0` address and array is continuous, so `sizeof(struct abc) == (char*)&arr[1] - (char*)&arr[2]`. So compiler does padding on the end of the struct, so that the next array element is properly aligned. || `If you do use aligned(12)` - btw, `12` is invalid, padding has to be a power of 2 :p

Comment: `No, the attribute refers to the starting address of the struct, not it's size in memory` so can it be used to fake memory address for security purposes to prevent against buffer over flow.  because this way if someone knows my function code then I can just do alignment to tweak address space of the function. in a way

Comment: @KamilCuk - yes, you are right about arrays, I didn't want to overburden with details.
Alex - It's possible, but usually a canary is used to fend off buffer overflows. Alignments remain constant after compilation so an attacker would just adjust his payload to overcome your padding.

Comment: `usually a canary is used to fend off buffer overflows` what's that means. please clarify

Comment: @immortal how canary is checked if there is a separate thread that does check canary value and if changed just shut the server down?

Comment: Canary are a few random bytes that are written between buffers. It's usually done on the stack, and when the function exits those bytes are checked to see they weren't overwritten. If they are the program usually exits. Regarding threaded models and global buffers, it's obviously more complex, but similar mechanisms can be used (increase buffer size a bit, write some random bytes in the end, check them before each use)

Comment: You could add that specifying alignment is typically not needed for "normal" built-in types: The compiler by default generates code with a suitable alignment. One important use case is to properly align non-standard integer types for SSE.

Comment: For example, see this old thread: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206. Strictly spoken, malloc (i.e., the libc routine interfacing with the operating system) -- which is type agnostic -- should always return memory which is aligned for *all* types in the system, that is, is suitably aligned for the type with the most demanding alignment requirements. __m128 has an extraordinary alignment requirement of 16 which would be excessive to apply to all and any mallocs, so the default is only 8. (This may be solved by now, if only by https://www.bfilipek.com/2019/08/newnew-align.html.)